# Working with Duration (Availability) in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a line graph in PowerBI. What I am trying to plot is somewhat complex.

I have the following tables:

Staffing - this table describes staffing for every employee in the company. By "staffing" I'm referring to how their time is allocated. For example, Employee #7 is staffed in "Chicken Manufacturing" with a StartDate of 1/1/2016 and an EndDate of 1/10/2016

```
EmployeeID   Project                  StartDate       EndDate
5            Cutting Lemons          12/1/2015       12/31/2015
5            Chicken Manufacturing    1/1/2016        1/10/2016
6            Fishing Lobsters         1/2/2016        1/5/2016
7            Chicken Manufacturing    1/5/2016        2/1/2016
8            Drinking                 2/1/2016        null
```

I also have a standard Date dimension as well as an Employees table and a Project table. The Employees table has a row for every employee and the Project has a row for each activity.

I am trying to create a line graph that has dates on the x-axis and the line will show me how many employees are active at the given date. So for dates 12/1/2015 - 1/10/2016 Employee 5 should be counted as "Staffed" but on 1/11/2016, he should not be included in the total.

What I'm *actually* trying to do is calculate Availability and by that I mean, how many Employee hours are available on each day (I have a project called Available) so ultimately I will want to count the number of Hours rather than employees, but I think if I can get to work with counting employees, I shouldn't have too much trouble multiplying number of employees by 8 hours per day.

Comment: Well I have about 6 measures, none of which work. In the past when I've done cumulative totals I always just did something like CALCULATE( Staffing, DATESMTD('Date') ), but as I need daily totals, I've been trying variations such as Measure = CALCULATE( sum( Staffing[Availability Hours column] ), DATESINPERIOD( Staffing[StartDate], MAX(Staffing[StartDate]), 1000, DAY))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Count of Emp =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Employee[EmployeeID] ),
    FILTER (
        Staffing,
        [StartDate] <= MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
            && (
                [EndDate] >= MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
                    || ISBLANK ( [EndDate] )
            )
    )
)
```

It is not tested but should work as long as you have relatinship between Employee - Staffing. Also be sure to use your date column in the Axis setting.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It helps, but it still does not work :(

The line from the measure exactly matches a line that is just a simple count of employeeID

Comment: @john5, what do you mean? What should be your expected result based on the data you posted in the OP?

Comment: Ok based on your formula here is what I think is happening:

I think your formula is re-counting every line for every date. So when I have Employee 5 starting on 1/1/2016 and Employee 7 starting a project on 1/1/2016, it is counting that as 4, when it should be counting it as 2 - because it's perfoming the count for 1/1/2016 for Employee 5 and then doing another count for 1/1/2016 for Employee 7

Comment: @john5, basically my expression count the different employees working in a project in a given date. Is not it what you need?